# ignore service volumes_from

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
version: '2'
services:
  service-one:
    image: image_one
    volumes_from:
      - container:some_container
  service-two:
    image: image_two
```

The problem is, if I want to run `docker-compose up service-two`, docker will complain that `some_container` does not exist even though `some_container` is a dependency of `service-on` and not `service-two`.

How can I ignore the service-one dependencies since I don't need that container at that time?

Comment: I see no dependency defined for service-two at all. Is this your full `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: @DanLowe exactly my point :) - docker-compose still looks for `some_container`'s existence even though i just wanna running `service-two`